# Passing ID parameter from url to a php script using $routeParams in AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-routing, routeparams

I like to pass ID parameter to php so that I can retrieve a particular row of sql database inside the script.

The ID parameter is available in URL, for example (http://localhost/RoutingAngularJS/index.php#/students/1). That last digit 1 is the row id in database so that information of a person in that row can be retrieved.

$routeParams is used in controller as

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
             .config(function($routeProvider){
             $routeProvider
             .
             .when("/students/:id", {
                 templateUrl:"Templates/studentDetails.html",
                 controller:"studentDetailsController"
             })
        })
          .controller("studentDetailsController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
                 $http({
                     url:"api/ReadOneStudent.php",
                        params:{id:$routeParams.id},
                     method: "get"

                 }).then(function(response){
                    $scope.student = response.records;
                 })               
            });
```

My ReadOneStudent.php is

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
// include database and object files  
    include_once 'database.php'; 
    include_once 'Students.php';

    // instantiate database and product object 
    $database = new Database(); 
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    // initialize object
    $student = new Students($db);

    // get id of product to be edited
    //$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));     

    // set ID property of product to be edited
    $student->id = ????;

    // read the details of product to be edited
    $student->readOneStudent();

    // create array
    $student_arr[] = array(
        "id" =>  $student->id,
        "name" => $student->name,
        "gender" => $student->gender,
        "city" => $product->city
    );
    echo '{"records":[' . $student_arr . ']}'; 
    // make it json format
    //print_r(json_encode($student_arr));

?>
```

I like to pass id to $student->id, now is with ????.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
                 .config(function($routeProvider){
                 $routeProvider
                 .
                 .when("/students/:id", {
                     templateUrl:"Templates/studentDetails.html",
                     controller:"studentDetailsController"
                 })
            })
              .controller("studentDetailsController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
                     $http({
                         url:"api/ReadOneStudent.php",
                            params:$routeParams,
                         method: "get"

                     }).then(function(response){
                        $scope.student = response.data;
                     })               
                });
```

ReadOneStudent.php

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
// include database and object files  
    include_once 'database.php'; 
    include_once 'Students.php';

    // instantiate database and product object 
    $database = new Database(); 
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    // initialize object
    $student = new Students($db);

    // get id of product to be edited
    //$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));     

    // set ID property of product to be edited
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
        http_response_code(400); // bad request
        exit;
    }

    $student->id = $_GET['id'];

    // read the details of product to be edited
    $found = $student->readOneStudent(); // assuming this returns something useful
    if (!$found) {
        http_response_code(404);
        exit;
    }

    // create array
    // Seeing as this is called "read ONE student", why return an array?
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode([
        'id'     => $student->id,
        'name'   => $student->name,
        'gender' => $student->gender,
        'city'   => $student->city
    ]); // maybe you can even just use json_encode($student)
    exit;
    // make it json format
    //print_r(json_encode($student_arr));

?>
```

Students.php

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
    class Students{ 
        // database connection and table name 
        private $conn; 
        private $table_name = "tblStudents"; 

        // object properties 
        public $id; 
        public $name; 
        public $gender; 
        public $city; 

        // constructor with $db as database connection 
        public function __construct($db){ 
            $this->conn = $db;
        }            
        public function readOneStudent(){

            // query to read single record
            $query = "SELECT 
                        id, name, gender, city  
                      FROM 
                        " . $this->table_name . "
                      WHERE 
                        id = ?
                      LIMIT 
                        0,1";

            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

            // bind id of product to be updated
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

            // execute query
            $stmt->execute();

            // get retrieved row
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // set values to object properties
            $this->name = $row['name'];
            $this->gender = $row['gender'];
            $this->city = $row['city'];
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Simply use `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Also, 1) **NEVER** roll your own JSON; use `json_encode`. 2) You'll want to use `response.data.records` in the `then()` callback

Comment: You have two dots `..` between `$routeProvider` and `when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some strange things you're doing here. First, your PHP

**Students.php** - make `readOneStudent()` return something useful

```
if (!$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    return false;
}

// set values to object properties
$this->name = $row['name'];
$this->gender = $row['gender'];
$this->city = $row['city'];

$stmt->closeCursor();
return true;
```

**ReadOneStudent.php** - respond with useful statuses and JSON

```
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    http_response_code(400); // bad request
    exit;
}

$student->id = $_GET['id'];
if (!$student->readOneStudent()) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit;
}

// Seeing as this is called "read ONE student", why return an array?
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
    'id'     => $student->id,
    'name'   => $student->name,
    'gender' => $student->gender,
    'city'   => $student->city
]); // maybe you can even just use json_encode($student)
exit;
```

Next, I'd use the `resolve` property in the route configuration

```
$routeProvider.when("/students/:id", {
    templateUrl: "Templates/studentDetails.html",
    controller:"studentDetailsController",
    resolve: {
        student: function($routeParams, $http) {
            return $http.get('api/ReadOneStudent.php', {
                params: {id: $routeParams.id}
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data
            });
        }
    }
 })
```

and finally in your controller

```
.controller('studentDetailsController', function($scope, student) {
    $scope.student = student;
})
```

Comment: I have updated changes in EDIT in the original post. If I used resolve as you suggested and controller setting, I got 400 error, that means id is no proper id. If I do as shown in my EDIT, I have 404 error, can't find the row with id. What could be wrong?

Comment: @batuman I guess you missed the comment *"assuming this returns something useful"* as your `readOneStudent()` method doesn't return anything

Comment: @batuman I've updated my answer with some improvements. I may have been wrong to try and use `params: $routeParams`. Please see my new answer

Comment: Now is working. I need to delete  ! at if(!$student->readOneStudent());. Thanks

Comment: @batuman not sure I understand that. That check is there in case the query returns zero rows

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$_GET['id']` to get access to the GET with key *id* in PHP